# Multi-item Path Query with PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

With the following PostgreSQL 9.2.2 table:

```
  id    | parent_id
--------+----------
 body   | null
 head   | body
 mouth  | head
 eye    | head
 tooth  | mouth
 tongue | mouth
 sclera | eye
 cornea | eye
```

I need an output where all direct indirect parents are listed for every non-parent child, as such:

```
tooth   mouth
tooth   head
tooth   body
tongue  mouth
tongue  head
tongue  body
sclera  eye
sclera  head
sclera  body
cornea  eye
cornea  head
cornea  body
```

I've tried searching, my results only showed single item queries using with-recursive, like:

```
WITH RECURSIVE t AS ( 
SELECT  parent_id, id 
FROM    item_tree 
WHERE   child_id = id 
UNION ALL 
SELECT  it.parent_id, it.id
    FROM    item_tree it 
JOIN    t 
ON  it.child_id = t.parent_id
) 
SELECT  id, child_id 
FROM    t
```

I can externally program a loop replacing the `id` each time, but can it be done in SQL only?

@Daniel,

Here's the output of your original query:

```
  id     parent_id
  ------ ---------
  cornea eye
  cornea NULL
  cornea head
  cornea body
  sclera eye
  sclera head
  sclera NULL
  sclera body
  tongue body
  tongue head
  tongue NULL
  tongue mouth
  tooth  body
  tooth  head
  tooth  mouth
  tooth  NULL
```

However, it gives the desired, if you enclose it with a null-filtered select statement, even if you delete the inner null filters, like the following:

```
  select * from (
     WITH RECURSIVE t(id,parent_id) AS ( 
     select id,parent_id from item_tree i
     UNION ALL
     select t.id,i.parent_id from item_tree i JOIN t on i.id=t.parent_id 
     )
     select * from t order by id
  ) t1 where parent_id is not null;
```

Anyway, I've clicked the check mark since this may be a bug (I've tried running both queries via jdbc and in pgAdmin3 with the same outputs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the table's structure is **item_tree** ( `id` text, `parent_id` text ), a recursive query could start with the leaf elements as you define them (i.e., that are not parent to anything), and the top-level elements with a null `parent_id` have to be filtered, too:

```
select id,parent_id from item_tree i
 where parent_id is not null and
  id not in  (select parent_id from item_tree where parent_id is not null)
```

and then just crawl the (parent_id,id) relationships to the top of the tree.

Complete query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE t(id,parent_id) AS ( 
select id,parent_id from item_tree i where parent_id is not null 
   and id not in  (select parent_id from item_tree where parent_id is not null)
UNION ALL
 select t.id,i.parent_id from item_tree i JOIN t on i.id=t.parent_id 
)
select * from t order by id;
```

**EDIT**:
The above query includes in its output the NULLs at the top of the hierarchy. To exclude them, this modified version may be used instead. The final result should be the same than the query in the edited question with the outer-filtering.

```
WITH RECURSIVE t(id,parent_id) AS ( 
select id,parent_id from item_tree i where parent_id is not null 
   and id not in  (select parent_id from item_tree where parent_id is not null)
UNION ALL
 select t.id,i.parent_id from item_tree i JOIN t on i.id=t.parent_id
   where i.parent_id is not null 
)
select * from t order by id;
```

Comment: Thanks. It's the script I need, but the null filters don't seem to work; enclosing the recursive query with a select-parent_id-null filter does. I hope you won't mind editing your code, so I can click the check mark on your answer :))